# Getting url params in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I recently started learning React and Gatsby. my page has some URL parameters, how can I get it and put in `href` attr? Everything works on my local machine. But after gatsby build my variable `url = undefined` always.

```
import React from 'react';

const url = typeof window !== `undefined` ? window.location.search : ``;

const Article = ({
  content: {
    text,
    limit,
    rate,
    term,
    link,
    logo: {
      title,
      file: {
        URL,
      },
    },
  },
}) => {

  return (
    <Articles>
      <div>
        <button className="btn">
          <a href={url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" id="link-mfo">
            Получить деньги
          </a>
        </button>
      </div>
    </Articles>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `useState` to store that data and make them available in every change to your `href` attribute. Something like this should do the trick:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    
const Article = ({
  content: {
    text,
    limit,
    rate,
    term,
    link,
    logo: {
      title,
      file: {
        URL,
      },
    },
  },
}) => {
  const [urlParams, setUrlParams] = useState(``);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof window !==`undefined`){
      const queryString = window.location.search;
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      if(urlParams){
        setUrlParams(urlParams);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Articles>
      <div>
        <button className="btn">
          <a href={urlParams} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" id="link-mfo">
            Получить деньги
          </a>
        </button>
      </div>
    </Articles>
  );
};
```

This is basically a classic combination of `useState` and `useEffect` hooks. Once the DOM tree is loaded (empty `deps`, `[]`) the function to get the URL parameters is triggered and stores the result in `setUrlParams`. Finally, you are passing the value in the `href` attribute by `href={urlParams}`. Of course, you can find other workarounds.

Your statement:

```
const url = typeof window !== `undefined` ? window.location.search : ``;
```

Set as a `const`, it was fixing the value in the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering), because is where `gatsby build` occurs, to `undefined` and was never updated.

Comment: Thanks! That works for me. but now if url has no params I get null. How I can do checking if var url is not empty? For example my link: https://example.com/?null, I want to remove this null from URL  and use only if var URL is not empty

Comment: Wrap it inside a condition: `if(urlParams) setUrlParams(urlParams)`. If the URL comes without parameters, it will take the initial value set in `useState(``)` (empty string).